# Dynamically generate breadcrumb link base on current hashed URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I used to have my URL look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/url-groups/edit/14
```

Now they look like this

```
http://localhost:8080/#/url-groups/edit/14
```

This fn used to slice it up nicely

```
links: function () {
    return [
        { text: 'Home', disabled: false, href: '/' },
        // { text: this.title, disabled: true, href: 'breadcrumbs_link_2' },
        ...new URL(window.location.href).pathname
            .split('/')
            .slice(1)
            .map((seg) => ({ text: seg, disabled: false, href: seg }))
    ]
}
```

To Home > URL Group > Edit > 14

How can I modify above fn() to work with my new URL format ?

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/grh1n6mt/

Answer (score 2):

Split the pathname by `/` replace `''` by `Home` then join them using `>`
:

```js
links: function () {
    return new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/')
                                                 .map(token=>token?token:'Home')
                                                 .join(' > ')
    
}
```

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/ejUSqvFb0Cod.png

Comment: what's the output?